# How can I restart my audio more easily?

Tags: audio, windows-shell

A recurrent problem with my Windows 10 speakers can be solved with [method 4 here](https://appuals.com/windows-shell-common-dll-has-stopped-working/), a PowerShell solution that requires a restart. Is there a way I can make the effect immediate, so that a restart is not required? Going one step further, can I reduce the fix to a 1-click method, such as with a desktop .bat?

Conexant SmartAudio HD is the culprit. I stumbled on my current approach when seeking a workaround to the fact that, because the Volume Mixer crashes due to a Windows Shell Common DLL problem, I can't disable audio enhancements the usual way. If there's a permanent remedy to this problem, I'd be grateful.

Comment: That certificate allow change should stick.  Is this your personal computer?  And/or is it on a domain network?  "can I reduce the fix to a 1-click method, such as with a desktop .bat?" Yes, you can make a batch file that launches PowerShell and a PS1 script, but we're not a script-writing service, so what have you researched/tried so far, and where are you getting stuck?  Re: your actual problem: Are you using the most recent Conexant driver/utilities?

Comment: @Techle007 The drivers are up to date. I've read a little about ps1 scripts, but suspect a restart would still be needed. Can adding a suitable line of code remove said need?

Comment: The certificate store takes effect at Windows startup, for security reasons, because of that there's no way to apply the changes that Powershell command makes, without restarting windows.  Really though, that just a workaround for a different problem you should concentrate on the actual problem, instead of the problem you're having with your supposed solution.  Doing so is referred to as an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info].  to that end, as I asked before, is this your personal computer, or is it a work computer?

Comment: @Techle007 Personal.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your audio properties, disable the audio card and then enable it.

If after disabling the device, it is gone, right click and select: show hidden devices.

I do this when my soundcard for unknown reasons stops working. Should restore sound and stuff in most cases and doesn't require a restart.

Not sure if and how you can automate that though.